# Why GCP Pub/Sub Subscription Fails to Acknowledge Messages?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a issue with GCP Pub/Sub Subscriber message acknowledgment. I have written three classes: PubSubPublisher (publish to topic), PubSubSubscriber (receive from subscription and index to elasticsearch) and ElasticDailyIndexManager(Thread). That's what I do with them:

1. I publish 100k dummy messages to my topic (it's done with around 10k messages per second) using PubSubPublisher.
2. I run PubSubSubscriber.receive_and_index() for the first time. While it processess the messages it also indexes it into Elasticsearch using 10 ElasticDailyIndexManager Threads. Basically I connect to subscription & read (and index) for 60 seconds and exit. 100k are indexed into Elasticsearch (it's done with around 1.5k messages per second).
3. I run PubSubSubscriber.receive_and_index() second time - I expect nothing to be indexed, however, around 40k new documents are indexed (Id is random in elasticsearch).

Sometimes it needs around 3-4 runs to empty subscription so I guess there is issue with acknowleding messages but there are no errors during runtime. I index data along with message.message_id and it's clear that I have multiple rows with the same message_id.

I don't see the reason why subscriber would fail to acknowledge as it doesn't throw any errors. I have set 30 second acknowledgment timeout on subscription but it didn't help.

Below code for mentioned classes:

```
class ProcessFutures(Thread):
    def __init__(self, futures_queue):
        Thread.__init__(self)

        self.queue = futures_queue

        self.counter = 0

        self.results = list()

        self.daemon = True

        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while getattr(self, 'keep_going', True):
            future = self.queue.get()

            self.results.append(future.result())

            self.queue.task_done()


class PubSubPublisher:
    def __init__(self, project_id, topic_name):
        self.client = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
        self.project_id = project_id
        self.topic_name = topic_name

        self.keep_going = True
        self.futures_queue = Queue()
        self.future_process = ProcessFutures(self.futures_queue)

    def publish_message(self, message_body):
        """
        Publishes message to a Pub/Sub topic.

        future.result is verified in separate thread to avoid blocking of message publishing.
        """

        topic_path = self.client.topic_path(self.project_id, self.topic_name)

        if isinstance(message_body, dict):
            data = dumps(message_body)
        elif isinstance(message_body, str):
            data = message_body
        else:
            raise BaseException

        data = data.encode('utf-8')

        future = self.client.publish(topic_path, data=data)

        self.futures_queue.put(future)

    def finish(self):
        self.future_process.queue.join()

        print("Processed results: " + str(len(self.future_process.results)))


@click.command()
@click.option('--project-id', '-p', required=True, type=str, help='Google Cloud Platform Project Id')
@click.option('--topic', '-t', required=True, type=str, help='Pub/Sub Topic to which messages will be published')
@click.option('--message', '-m', required=True, type=str, help='Message body')
@click.option('--amount', '-a', required=True, type=int, help='How many messages to send')
def run(project_id, topic, message, amount):
    from time import time

    psp = PubSubPublisher(project_id, topic)

    time_start = time()

    for i in range(amount):
        message_body = dict(i=i, message=message)
        psp.publish_message(message_body)

    psp.finish()

    time_stop = time()

    seconds = time_stop - time_start

    print("Published {} messages in {:.2f} seconds. That is {:.2f} mps!".format(amount, seconds,
                                                                                amount / seconds))

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, ElasticsearchException, NotFoundError, helpers
from datetime import datetime
from json import load
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
from os import getenv

from config import BASE_PATH


class ElasticDailyIndexManager(Thread):
    def __init__(self, index_basename):
        Thread.__init__(self)

        es_port = 9200 if ElasticDailyIndexManager.str_to_bool(getenv("RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER", "False")) else 9201
        es_url = "elastic" if ElasticDailyIndexManager.str_to_bool(getenv("RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER", "False")) else "localhost"

        self.es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[es_url], port=es_port)

        self.index_template_name = index_basename
        self.index_name_mask = index_basename if index_basename.endswith("-") else index_basename + "-"

        while not self._template_exists():
            self._register_index_template()

        self.queue = Queue()
        self.daemon = True

        self.start()

    def run(self):
        def generator():
            while True:
                message_body, message_id = self.queue.get()

                metadata = dict()
                self.queue.task_done()

                yield self._prepare_bulk_doc(message_body, **metadata)

        bulk_load = helpers.streaming_bulk(self.es, generator(), 10, yield_ok=False)

        while True:
            for success, info in bulk_load:
                print(success, info)

    def index_document(self, document_body, id=None):
        document_body['@timestamp'] = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

        try:
            self.es.index(index=self.index_name_mask + datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y.%m.%d'),
                          doc_type='default',
                          body=document_body,
                          id=id)
        except ElasticsearchException as e:
            print(document_body, id, e.args)

    def _register_index_template(self):
        template_body = self._get_json_file_content("{}/config/templates/{}.json".format(BASE_PATH,
                                                                                         self.index_template_name))

        try:
            if template_body is not None:
                self.es.indices.put_template(name=self.index_template_name,
                                             body=template_body,
                                             master_timeout="60s")

        except ElasticsearchException as e:
            print(e.args)

    def _template_exists(self):
        try:
            self.es.indices.get_template(self.index_template_name)
            return True
        except NotFoundError:
            return False

    @staticmethod
    def _get_json_file_content(file_dir_arg):
        """
        Wrapper on load function. Expects file with JSON inside.

        :param file_dir_arg: Path to file to be read.
        :return: Dictionary (Encoded JSON)
        """
        result = None

        try:
            with open(file_dir_arg, 'r', encoding='UTF-8-SIG') as f:
                result_tmp = f
                result = load(result_tmp)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e.args)

        return result

    def _prepare_bulk_doc(self, source_arg, **kwargs):
        """
        Function providing unified document structure for indexing in elasticsearch.
        The structure needs to be compliant with

        :param index_arg: index to which send data
        :param doc_type_arg: document type in index_arg
        :param source_arg: body of document
        :param kwargs: additional meta parameters (like doc _id)
        :return: Reformatted & enhanced source_arg
        """

        metadata = dict(**kwargs).get('metadata', dict())

        source_arg['@timestamp'] = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

        result = {
            '_index': self.index_name_mask + datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y.%m.%d'),
            '_type': 'default',
            '_op_type': 'index',
            'doc': source_arg,
            'doc_as_upsert': False
        }

        result.update(metadata)

        return result

    @staticmethod
    def str_to_bool(str_arg):
        if str_arg.lower() == 'true':
            return True
        elif str_arg.lower() == 'false':
            return False
        else:
            return None


ELASTIC_MANAGERS = environ.get("ElASTIC_MANAGERS", 10)


class PubSubSubscriber:
    def __init__(self, project_id_arg, topic_name_arg, seconds_arg=None):
        self.elasticsearch_index_managers = list()

        for _ in range(ELASTIC_MANAGERS):
            self.elasticsearch_index_managers.append(ElasticDailyIndexManager(topic_name_arg))

        self.project_id = project_id_arg
        self.topic_name = topic_name_arg

        self.client = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()

        self.counter = 0

        self.latencies = list()

        self.seconds = seconds_arg

        self.lock = Lock()

    def receive_and_index(self):
        subscription_path = self.client.subscription_path(self.project_id,
            "{}-subscription-elastic".format(self.topic_name))

        def callback(message):
            latency = message._received_timestamp - message.publish_time.timestamp()

            document = PubSubSubscriber.struct_message(message.data)
            document['message_id'] = message.message_id

            self.elasticsearch_index_managers[self.counter % ELASTIC_MANAGERS].queue.put((document, None))

            message.ack()

            if self.seconds:
                self.latencies.append(latency)

            self.counter += 1

        future = self.client.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)

        try:
            # When timeout is unspecified, the result method waits indefinitely.
            print('Listening for messages on {}'.format(subscription_path))
            print('Running for{}'.format(' ' + str(self.seconds) + 'seconds...' if self.seconds else 'ever'))

            future.result(timeout=self.seconds)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Listening for messages on {} threw an Exception: {}.'.format(subscription_path, e))
        finally:
            time_queue_join_start = time()

            for manager in self.elasticsearch_index_managers:
                manager.queue.join()

            time_queue_join_stop = time()

            self.seconds = self.seconds + time_queue_join_stop - time_queue_join_start

            print("Read {} messages in {:.2f} seconds. That is {:.2f} mps!".format(self.counter, self.seconds,
                                                                                   self.counter / self.seconds))

            if self.latencies:
                avg_latency = float(sum(self.latencies)) / float(len(self.latencies))

                print("Average latency was {:.2f} ms.".format(avg_latency))

    @staticmethod
    def struct_message(message_arg, encoding='utf-8'):
        if isinstance(message_arg, dict):
            message = message_arg
        elif isinstance(message_arg, bytes):
            message = PubSubSubscriber.message_to_dict(message_arg.decode(encoding))
        elif isinstance(message_arg, str):
            message = PubSubSubscriber.message_to_dict(message_arg)
        else:
            message = None

        group_topics = message.get("group", dict()).get("group_topics", dict())

        if group_topics:
            message['group']['group_topics'] = [d['topic_name'] for d in message['group']['group_topics']]

        # time handling
        event_time = PubSubSubscriber.epoch_to_strtime(message.get("event", dict()).get("time", None))
        if event_time:
            message['event']['time'] = event_time

        mtime = PubSubSubscriber.epoch_to_strtime(message.get("mtime", None))
        if mtime:
            message['mtime'] = mtime

        # geo handling
        group_geo_lat = message.get("group", dict()).get("group_lat", None)
        group_geo_lon = message.get("group", dict()).get("group_lon", None)

        if group_geo_lon and group_geo_lat:
            message['group']['group_geo'] = PubSubSubscriber.create_geo_object(group_geo_lat, group_geo_lon)

        venue_geo_lat = message.get("venue", dict()).get("lat", None)
        venue_geo_lon = message.get("venue", dict()).get("lon", None)

        if venue_geo_lon and venue_geo_lat:
            message['venue']['venue_geo'] = PubSubSubscriber.create_geo_object(venue_geo_lat, venue_geo_lon)

        return message

    @staticmethod
    def epoch_to_strtime(epoch_time):
        try:
            result = strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', localtime(epoch_time / 1000))
        except:
            result = epoch_time

        return result

    @staticmethod
    def create_geo_object(lat, lon):
        return "{}, {}".format(str(lat), str(lon))

    @staticmethod
    def message_to_dict(message_arg):
        keep_going = True
        result = message_arg

        while keep_going and (not isinstance(result, dict)):
            try:
                result = loads(result)
            except JSONDecodeError:
                result = None
                keep_going = False

        return result


@click.command()
@click.option('--project-id', '-p', required=True, type=str, help='Google Cloud Platform Project Id')
@click.option('--topic', '-t', required=True, type=str, help='Pub/Sub Topic from which messages will be read')
@click.option('--seconds', '-s', default=None, required=False, type=int, help='For how long to read messages. If not provided - run forever')
def run(project_id, topic, seconds):
    pss = PubSubSubscriber(project_id, topic, seconds)
    pss.receive_and_index()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: Are you sure your subscribers are strong enough to pull and process all 100k messages in the 60s period that you're reading. For example do your metrics show at least 100k pull operations in a single run?

Also keep in mind that PubSub is at 'at least once' system and if you want to not duplicate entries you'll need to make your functions idempotent.

Answer (score 3):

From https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/faq#duplicates:

> **Why are there too many duplicate messages?**
>
> Cloud Pub/Sub guarantees at-least-once message delivery, which means that occasional duplicates are to be expected. However, a high rate of duplicates may indicate that the client is not acknowledging messages within the configured `ack_deadline_seconds`, and Cloud Pub/Sub is retrying the message delivery. This can be observed in the [monitoring metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics) `pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/pull_ack_message_operation_count` for pull subscriptions, and `pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/push_request_count` for push subscriptions. Look for elevated `expired` or `webhook_timeout` values in the `/response_code`. This is particularly likely if there are many small messages, since Cloud Pub/Sub may batch messages internally and a partially acknowledged batch will be fully redelivered.
>
> Another possibility is that the subscriber is not acknowledging some messages because the code path processing those specific messages fails, and the Acknowledge call is never made; or the push endpoint never responds or responds with an error.